# Simple random walk on a hypercube

Tags: python, simulation, random-walk

I have written a code for a lazy simple random walk on a n-dimensional hypercube. To visualize it, one can think of a 2D square or a 3D cube with the corners of the square/cube being the vertices of a graph. The walk on this graph starts at the origin and with probability 0.5 stays at a vertex and with remaining equal probability visits its neighbors. The code is running but I have a technical question. I will explain what I did in a bit but at the end, the distance between stationary distribution which is uniform and the distribution obtained by simulation has to decrease to 0 as time increases. In my simulation, for large n, say n=10, the distance between the above distributions tapers off at a non-zero value. It would be great if someone can point out where I went wrong?!

1. This function generates all vertices of a n-dim hypercube, output is a list of bitstring lists i.e. each vertex of the hypercube is a n-bitstring and there are 2^n such vertices.

   ```
    def generateAllBinaryStrings(n, arr, l, i):  

        if i == n: 
            l.append(arr[:]) 
            return

        arr[i] = 0
        generateAllBinaryStrings(n, arr, l, i + 1)  

        arr[i] = 1
        generateAllBinaryStrings(n, arr, l, i + 1)  

        return l
   ```
2. Creating a dictionary whose keys are vertices and values are the neighbors (each vertex has n neighbors)

   ```
    def dictionary(v):
        d={}
        for i in range(len(v)):
            d[str(v[i])]=[]
            temp=[]
            for j in range(n):
                temp=v[i][:]
                if v[i][j]==1:
                    temp[j]=0
                else:
                    temp[j]=1
                d[str(v[i])].append(temp)
        return d
   ```
3. simple random walk on the n-dim cube starting at the origin (output is a list of vertices visited in time t)

   ```
    def srw(d,n,t):
        h=[[0 for i in range(n)]]
        w=[1/(2*n) for i in range(n)]
        w.append(0.5)
        for i in range(t):
            temp=d[str(h[-1])][:]
            temp.append(h[-1])
            h.append(random.choices(temp,weights=w)[-1])

        return h
   ```
4. Finding L1 distance between stationary distribution and simulated distribution

   ```
    def tvDist(d,n,t,num):
        finalstate=[]
        for i in range(num):
            temp=srw(d,n,t)
            finalstate.append(temp[-1])
        temp2=[list(item) for item in set(tuple(row) for row in finalstate)]
        Xt={}
        for state in temp2:
            Xt[str(state)]=None
        for state in temp2:
            count=0
            for i in finalstate:
                if i==state:
                    count+=1
            Xt[str(state)]=count/num


        dist=0
        for state in d:
            if state in Xt:
                dist+=abs(Xt[str(state)]-(1/(2**n)))
            else:
                dist+=1/(2**n)
        dist=0.5*(dist)

        return dist
   ```
5. If you copy paste the code above and run the following (plotting the distance vs time for n=5,10)

   ```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import random
    import collections as cs

    time=30
    numsim=5000

    for n in range(5,11,5):

        l = []  
        arr = [None] * n 
        vertices=generateAllBinaryStrings(n, arr, l, 0)
        d=dictionary(vertices)
        tvdistance=[]
        for t in range(1,time):
            tvdistance.append(tvDist(d,n,t,numsim))
        plt.plot(tvdistance)

    plt.show()
   ```
6. I get this plot: (n=5 looks right but n=10 tapers off at a non-zero value)

[image]

Comment: This is a very interesting question. I'm reading your code, btw i think `if h[-1] not in temp:` will always be true because a vertex will never be its own neighbor (in this case) am I wrong?, so you can always do `temp.append(h[-1])` on step 3.

Comment: Another thing, you are doing `for state in temp2:` twice in step 4. You can initialize `Xt` with only one `for state in temp2:` i believe. I'm stll reading the code... :)

Comment: @JorgeMorgado Thanks, yes, it is. In fact, the distance versus time curve should be a phase transition curve for large n i.e. it should drop from 1 to 0 sharply. I don't remember the error I got in step 3, but I had to use that to fix the error.

Comment: I'm trying to understand step 4, can you summarize the idea? As i see `temp2` is a Set of the items from `finalstate` and `Xt` is the average of each item, Is that correct? If this is what I asked it can be done more easy I will show you how...I'm still reading code :)

Comment: @JorgeMorgado Take your time, thanks. Step 4 finds the probability distribution of the simulated walk at time t. `temp` has the set of vertices visited. `finalstate` is the last state/vertex visited over different simulations. Because a vertex can be visited more than once, `temp2` is the set of the list `finalstate`. Then the probability of each element in `temp2` is `count/num` i.e. number of times that vertex is visited divided by number of simulations, which is stored in the dictionary `Xt`. Hope that helps, let me know if there is a question!

Comment: @JorgeMorgado After that, `dist` measures the L1 distance between the probability distribution found above and the uniform probability distribution i.e. `1/2^n` for each vertex.

Comment: I see, of course, that has to decrease to 0, ok let me test the code and see if i can find the error. :)

Comment: @JorgeMorgado Perfect, appreciate that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222743/discussion-between-jorge-morgado-and-trickymaverick).

Comment: I really like this question. I had tried a similar random walk in x dimensions after doing a random walk in three, but I could never quite bring myself to trust my distance function which I based on vector mathematics. Your post and these comments are inspiring!

Comment: @user10637953 Thanks, yeah the code looks right for the most part except for some glitch.

Comment: @trickymaverick i think y have an answer for you open the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222743/discussion-between-jorge-morgado-and-trickymaverick) when you see this